# Graph for data updated every 30 minutes

Tags: mysql, charts, highcharts

I make weather station which uploads data to my MySQL database every 30-60 minutes. How to make on example temperature plot for a week on my website? I've looked for such option in Highcharts but I don't know does it is possible. Date and time is saved in database as timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

They have an example specifically for time data with irregular intervals: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

Comment: Yeah, but this example is only for date intervals. And I have got few readings every day.. On my plot there should be few points for every day. That's main problem.

Comment: That approach will work just fine with date and time. We did exactly that when we used this technique. If I recall correctly, the tricky part was getting the x-axis labels along the bottom to display how we wanted them to. I don't have that code anymore (it was done for a previous employer), or else I'd share the chart options we used, along with a fake sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Get your data from database for last week, then preprocess in backend to fit Highcharts data format, and as result you should have something like this:

```
var myData = [
                [1388534400000, 12],
                [next_timestamp, next_value],
                [another_timestamp, another_value],
                ...
             ]
```

Now you can use that data to generate chart:

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: myData
    }]
})
```

**Note**: timestamps are in milliseconds.

Now to update chart every 30minutes, just create call some AJAX call to get new data from the server:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('path/to/data', function(myData) {
        $("#container").highcharts().series[0].setData(myData);
    });
}, 30 * 60 * 1000); // 30minutes
```